# Running a java application VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a java application that consists of various files and I need to run my project. I have jdk 14 installed and have also set the Environment Variables. But when I click on Launch project, it just keeps loading and loading and nothing else happens. It does not show me any error log or anything. I am really confused and been trying to solve this for a week. In launch, it does not give me any option of java. It says Launch in angular.  Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Angular in any way is not related to running Java here... probably you have a wrong config

Comment: try entering the command that you will use to run the project into the program field

Comment: You can follow the steps on the VSCode docs [Java Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) You need to install the Java Language extension to add java related tasks.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is basically an editor for sourcecode files of different languages. As such, it does have any inbuilt Java execution options.

To debug your Java programs, you will need to install the appropriate Java extensions for VS Code.

Having Jdk installed is a prerequisite to use Java on VS Code but it alone is not enough.